# java replace list contents or to replace reference value itself

Tags: java, android

I have a list that used for adapter for ListView in Android.

Most time, the List is used for read but sometimes replace of all List contents is needed.

which type of code below (replaceListA, replaceListB) is preferred? or another way to replace the list?

thank you in advance.

```
private ArrayList<Model> list = new ArrayList<Model>();

public synchronized void replaceListA(List newList) {
            list.clear();
            list.addAll(newList);
}

public synchronized void replaceListB(List newList) {
    list = newList;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that `newList` would be edited after calling this method?

Comment: Generally, No. Is there different way needed? by situation?

Comment: If `newList` is updated after calling the method, it could change the value of `list` as well (if you use `replaceListB`). Depending on the situation, you might want that to happen or you might not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, `replaceListB` will probably run faster, but if `newList` is later modified, `list` will also change. For example:

```
ArrayList<Model> newList = new ArrayList<Model>();
replaceListB(newList);
newList.add( /*something*/ ); //This will update both newList and list
```

By contrast

```
ArrayList<Model> newList = new ArrayList<Model>();
replaceListA(newList);
newList.add( /*something*/ ); //This will only update newList
```

To be more specific, `replaceListB` will run in a constant amount of time, since it is only changing a pointer, where `replaceListA` has to copy over each element of the list individually, so it will take a long time if the list is large. However, depending on the details of the garbage collecter, it's possible that `replaceListA` could free up memory sooner. Either way, it is unlikely to make a major difference unless the lists are very large, so I would recommend choosing based on whether you want to make a separate copy of the list (`replaceListA`) or allow editing (`replaceListB`).

Answer (score 1):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6961394/1275092).

> It's hard to know without a benchmark, but if you have lots of items in your `ArrayList` and the average size is lower, it might be faster to make a new `ArrayList`.

Comment: You should just vote to close as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

The second is preferred.  It runs in O(1) time, the other runs in O(n) time.  Just be sure to call notifyDataSetChanged afterwards.