# The list is not filled

Tags: java

I am trying to nest data into a list, which I also add to another list. The challenge is to get a list of nested lists of data.

```
    String content1;
    String content2;

    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> listData = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> listDataOne = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        content1 = "one " + i;
        content2 = "two " + i;

        listDataOne.add(content1);
        listDataOne.add(content2);

        System.out.println(listDataOne);
        listData.add(listDataOne);
        System.out.println(listData); // [[one 2, two 2], [one 2, two 2], [one 2, two 2]]
        listDataOne.clear();
    }
    System.out.println(listData);  // [[], [], []]
```

But in the end, I get empty nested lists. **What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: `listDataOne.clear();`? I think you assume that the inner list and its values are copied when you put it into the outer list. But they're not. You `add` a reference. Therefore calling `clear` on the list inside the loop body will change the inner list because it's the same instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of your `for` loop you're clearing `listDataOne` and since `listData` has the same list reference, it gets cleared too. You need to replace

```
listDataOne.clear();
```

with

```
listDataOne = new ArrayList<>();
```

to preserve data.

Answer (score 0):

It's happing because `listData` is storing reference of `listDataOne` instead of value. So, when you clear the reference will have no value and when you update `listDataOne` all the reference to it will be updated.

```
    String content1;
    String content2;

    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> listData = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> listDataOne;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        listDataOne = new ArrayList<>();
        content1 = "one " + i;
        content2 = "two " + i;

        listDataOne.add(content1);
        listDataOne.add(content2);

        System.out.println(listDataOne);
        listData.add(listDataOne);
        System.out.println(listData);  
  }
    System.out.println(listData);
```

You should also go through this this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6961356/list-clear-vs-list-new-arraylistinteger).

Comment: I would also move the declaration of `listDataOne` into the loop to reduce the scope. It doesn't need to exist outside the loop.